# Dynamics CRM 2011 - FirstSelectedItemId not being passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

The following doesn't work and not sure why.

I should get the ID passed in as a param but it's always undefined.

Ribbon xml section.

```
<Actions>
                        <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:ct_/scripts/jqueryandjson2.js" FunctionName="isNaN" />
                        <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:ct_/scripts/MyJSLib.js" FunctionName="isNaN" />
                        <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:ct_/scripts/lead/ribbon.js" FunctionName="startDisqualifyLead">
                            <CrmParameter Value="FirstSelectedItemId" />
                        </JavaScriptFunction>
                    </Actions>
```

Javascript method.

```
function startDisqualifyLead(entityId) {
if (!entityId)
    entityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

alert(entityId); // always undefined.
```

}

Comment: Does this happen for new records as well as for existing records?

Comment: I have a rule that will only enable that button when only 1 record is selected, so only existing.

Comment: Also, I know that Xrm.Page.data.entity is not available form the homepage ribbon. This method is also called from the form/details view ribbon and works fine. Just the param is always undefined.

Comment: I had a look at the SDK and what you have looks correct. If you are calling the function from a HomePageGrid ribbon, then maybe try the 'FirstPrimaryItemId' CrmParameter? Let me know how this goes.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and got the same result. I did however get it working by importing and publishing using  Erik Pools ribbon editor. No clue why my stuff was not working when manually importing and publishing using MSDNs guide on how to import/export the ribbon.

Comment: @JonC, glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue:
http://www.dotnet-world.com/blog/net-world/microsoft-dynamics-crm/2012/02/17/microsoft-crm-online-javascript-on-form-xrm.page.data-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did however get it working by importing and publishing using Erik Pools ribbon editor. No clue why my stuff was not working when manually importing and publishing using MSDNs guide on how to import/export the ribbon.